# Get URL path from UIImage - Framework ImagePicker

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, swift-framework

I'm trying to get the path from UIImage (for multiple selections) which I just get from gallery using the framework [ImagePicker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker). I get UIImage from this method:

```
func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    //here I can recive the images from gallery   
}
```

On this func I need to save the path on a String

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A `UIImage` doesn't contain information about any URL or information about the path. You may save them in the documents directory of your app, and then you store the path in a variable.

I wouldn't recommend using a deprecated library, better use the default `UIImagePicker` and use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller)  delegate method like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49151088/2907715).

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` doesn't contain any information about asset `URL`. You should use `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` [imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller) for getting `URL` from 
`info` dictionary.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let imageURL = info[.imageURL] as? URL //here's your URL
}
```